# retreive Response Cookie to get token for downloading file using python

Tags: python, http, web, cookies

I have developed python script to download file once connecting to web site (username and password) and clicking on button export, i inspected the web page, gone to network then Response Cookies , i have CofaceToken to include but i can't get it dynamically with python in header

headers = {
"Cookie": "CofaceToken=????",
"X-Sos-Contract-Id": "CONT-01-350905320",
}

```
    if token_tag and token_tag.has_attr("value"):
        token = token_tag["value"]
        print(f"Extracted token: {token}")
        # Use 'token' in subsequent requests for data retrieval by adding it to headers or using it in the request payload
    else:
        print("Token extraction failed. Token input not found or has no value.") but no response
```

Comment: what do you use? `requests`, `urllib`, `Selenium`, something else? We can't read in your mind - you have to show all details in question (not in comments). And maybe better create `minimal working code` so we could test.